# .NET Application - Fetching Assembly/File Version confusing

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to read the version info of a Strong Named .NET (built using v4.0) assembly using ***Powershell v2***. I am using two different ways to do this, but the 2nd method always gives me the correct version information [although the 1st method was the obvious natural choice] :-

**Method 1:** `[Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName("C:\ManagedAssembly.exe").Version.ToString()`

gives the value as "**50.0.0.0**"

**Method 2:** `[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("C:\ManagedAssembly.exe").FileVersion`

gives the version correctly as "**50.0.0.93**"

Any idea why such a behaviour ?

Comment: How do you know that the above is wrong? Windows Explorer on Win 7 doesn't show the assembly version by default and instead shows the file version. Your two values for file and assembly versions look sensible.

Comment: Assembly Version and File Version can be set different in solution properties from Visual studio.

Comment: Got it. I just opened the AssemblyVersionInfo.cs file and observed the following entries - [assembly: AssemblyVersion("50.0.0.0")] & [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("50.0.0.93")] --- which makes sense.

Comment: +1 for the OP for using [Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName which gets the version info *without loading the assembly into the current app domain*. Most examples use [Assembly]::Loadxxx(), which can be problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Mistake & Ignorance. The AssemblyVersionInfo.cs file contains two entries -

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("50.0.0.0")]
```

&

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("50.0.0.93")]
```

So, the above code is absolutely fine.